# Python Selenium: How do I print the correct tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print by ID using Selenium. As far as I can tell, "a" is the tag and "title" is the attribute. See HTML below.

When I run the following code:

```
print(driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")[0].get_attribute('title'))
```

I get the output:

```
Zero Tolerance
```

So I'm getting the first attribute correctly. When I increment the code above:

```
print(driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")[1].get_attribute('title'))
```

My expected output is:

```
Aaliyah Love
```

However, I'm just getting blank. No errors. What am I doing incorrectly? Pls don't suggest using xpath or css, I'm trying to learn Selenium tags.

HTML:

```
<a class=" Link ScenePlayer-ChannelName-Link styles_1lHAYbZZr4 Link ScenePlayer-ChannelName-Link styles_1lHAYbZZr4" href="/en/channel/ztfilms" title="Zero Tolerance" rel="">Zero Tolerance</a>

...
<a class=" Link ActorThumb-ActorImage-Link styles_3dXcTxVCON Link ActorThumb-ActorImage-Link styles_3dXcTxVCON" href="/[RETRACTED]/Aaliyah-Love/63565" title="Aaliyah Love"
```

[image: Screenshot of HTML]

Comment: How do you know if it's a first element in the list ? There can be others `a` tag as well and may be they don't have `title` attribute

Comment: Can you expand on this? How would one determine this?

Comment: I can give the answer, but that will have to either with CSS or XPath, not sure why you don't want them.

Comment: Does that mean it's impossible to solve this with tag?

Comment: TAG_NAME is good locator, I'd say better than XPath at least, but your question could be solve by using `//a[@title]` XPath or CSS `a[title]`

Comment: To be clear would you suggest abandoning tags completely?

Comment: No I would not, use them but if you can not solve the problem, don't just stick to one locator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium locators are a toolbox and you're saying you only want to use a screwdriver (`By.TAG_NAME`) for all jobs. We aren't saying that you shouldn't use `By.TAG_NAME`, we're saying that you should use the right tool for the right job and sometimes (most times) `By.TAG_NAME` is not the right tool for the job. CSS selectors are WAY more powerful locators because they can search for not only tags but also classes, properties, etc.

It's hard to say for sure what's going on without access to the site/page. It could be that the entire page isn't loaded and you need to add a wait for the page to finish loading (maybe count links expected on the page?). It could be that your locator isn't specific enough and is catching other A tags that don't have a title attribute.

I would start by doing some debugging.

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('title'))
```

What does this print?

1. If it prints some blank lines sprinkled throughout the actual titles, your locator is probably not specific enough. Try a CSS selector

   ```
   links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title]")
   for link in links:
       print(link.get_attribute('title'))
   ```
2. If instead it returns some titles and then nothing but blank lines, the page is probably not fully loaded. Try something like

   ```
   count = 20 # the number of expected links on the page
   link_locator = (By.TAG_NAME, "a")
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda wd: len(wd.find_elements(link_locator)) == count)
   links = driver.find_elements(link_locator)
   for link in links:
       print(link.get_attribute('title'))
   ```